# Nginx 405 Not Allowed - PHPMAILER

Tags: php, email, nginx, phpmailer

I uploaded a website with a PHPMailer v5. It works well in localhost but when I tried it online, Nginx-405-not-allowed page shows. below is my configuration for my mail function.

```
  require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
  $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
  $mail->isSMTP();
  $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->Username = 'myaccount@gmail.com';
  $mail->Password = 'mypassword';
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
  $mail->Port = 587;
```

Comment: Nt an aswer, but it looks like you're using composer to get PHPMailer, but you're loading it wrong. You should only need to `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`, not go any deeper than that. When you're using composer it deals with autoloading for you.

Comment: So I will dispose my phpmailer sir @Synchro? In what alternative way I can access my web server provider email ? I can't do php mail() because external mailing services is preferable.

Comment: If your ISP blocks outbound SMTP they probably want you to use their mail servers - GoDaddy does this. Read their docs, or find a better ISP.

Comment: Yes.. that's what I've done and posted it as answer below! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer. The problem is in the web server provider. It seems like there are some web servers don't accept smtp.gmail.com and thus I created an email from the domain and set the host, username, password and as well as the port to what the **web server provider *provides***. Hope you guys visit here will solve your questions.